# How to delete folders from output of another command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to delete the folders that this command brings back

```
dir "DeleteMe" /AD /s
```

How do I get the output of that and remove those directories?

Comment: Anytime you think "i need to preform `command a` based on the outputs of `command b`, instantly think of pipes, or `for` loops

Comment: @Arescet, a pipe just works if the following command takes data at the _STDIN_ channel, so it can receive the data from the _STDOUT_ channel of the preceding command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple task to delete all subfolders in current folder with `DeleteMe` in folder name can be done with a batch file with following two lines:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir "*DeleteMe*" /AD /B /S') do rd /Q /S "%%F" 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** returns because of `/AD` only names of directories with full path without quotes because of `/B` in current directory and all subdirectories because of `/S`.

Those directories are removed by command **RD** with all files and subdirectories because of `/S` in quiet mode because of `/Q`.

Error messages of command **RD** output to **stderr** are suppressed by redirecting them to **nul** with `2>nul` as explained in Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). This is useful here as when a directory with `DeleteMe` in name contains itself subdirectories, those subdirectories are also returned by **DIR**, but were removed already before by command **RD** and therefore producing error messages which are never of interest.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `rd /?`